# Elements are auto inserted to std::map during invalid loop cout operation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    map<int, string> sample;
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
        sample[i] = 'i' + i;
    map<int, string>::iterator i = sample.begin();
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) 
    {
        cout << sample[j] << endl;
    }
    for (; i != sample.end(); i++)
        cout << i->first;
    cout << "Size is :" << sample.size();
}
```

I ran this program to know more about std::map ie I am getting map size as 10 and pls refer the below screenshot of output.

[image]

Could someone pls clarify me why std::map is auto extending in invalid loop display function .

Comment: FYI the output you are showing does not match your code.  When running I get: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c71efd9ed946206

Comment: I corrected the second for loop ie updating j value range to be 1 to 10 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map::operator [key]` is equivalent to `(*((this->insert(make_pair(key, mapped_type()))).first)).second`, so inserts a default value if element is not present.

You have to use `at` or `find` to not insert element in `map`, or use iterator.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone pls clarify me why std::map is auto extending in invalid
>   loop display function .

[*`std::map::operator`*[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, ***performing an insertion if such key does not already exist***.